# ¿Como comprobar si un input hidden ha sido manipulado?

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo comprobar la manipulación de un `input` de tipo `hidden` pasando como valor un `id`?

**Código:**

```
<input name="id" id="id" type="hidden" value="$id" />
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "evitar la manipulación"? ¿Puedes añadir más detalles de qué es lo que quieres?

Comment: Digamos, alguien puede cambiar el value del formulario y puede afectar a otro $id que no debía ser alterado

Comment: ¿Y cómo se calcula ese input hidden? ¿En el servidor o en el cliente? Porque si es en el servidor, ni siquiera habría necesidad de un input hidden

Comment: Y si es en el cliente creo que es imposible evitar que alguien inspeccione un elemento y cambie su valor @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: @CamiloVasquez efectivamente

Comment: Nada humanamente posible evitará que alguien inspeccione/abra herramienta de desarrolladores/desactive js (para cualquier truco con js) y pueda modificar tus elementos a libre voluntad.

Comment: Sí, amigos, yo sé que eso es imposible. Tal vez formulé mal la pregunta.

Lo que quiero decir es; cómo evitar que ese cambio que haga el cliente afecte a un $id que no debe.

Comment: Bueno... lo de que es imposible que alguien lo inspeccione no creo... me parece que si se revisa el código fuente de la página se podrá ver que el input existe, y se podrá ver su valor... no lo he probado, pero me parece que es así. Si alguien lo ha probado que lo confirme @AlvaroMontoro y Camilo ¿?

Comment: en la consola de google, puedes editar directamente elementos de html, incluyendo pero no limitado a : agregar atributos, estilos inline, cambiar atributos, etc. El que esto afecte el submit lo desconozco

Comment: @A.Cedano Tienes razón se puede bloquear el clic derecho del mouse pero hay muchas mas formas de acceder al inspector de elementos y editar ese input

Comment: José, si el input está oculto, no creo que el cliente pueda bajo ningún concepto modificar su valor. Él podrá ver lo que hay en el input examinando el código fuente, pero modificarlo para enviarlo al servidor, no creo que eso sea posible.

Comment: @A.Cedano hice una prueba en *localhost* y desde el navegador puedes ver el valor de los `inputs hidden` como dices, y también pude cambiar su valor, es decir, modificar el `value` de `id` `1` a `2` y hacer el `submit`. Existe herramientas que ofrecen los navegadores mismo hoy en día, que son para el desarrollador, parecido a `firebug`, donde puedes inspeccionar y editar el código para hacer pruebas, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yo para un formulario de update guardo el ID en un hidden y en otro hidden el mismo ID pero hasheado, entonces cuando se trata actualizar el contenido tira error si no coinciden la ID y el hash al hacer la verificacion desde mi php (antes de la sentencia de update) ...

```
$id = $row['id'];
$hash = hash('crc32b', $row['id']);
```

y antes de pasar por la parte del SQL hago un hasheo de nuevo del $id para comparar con $hash, si coinciden ya pasa al SQL, caso contrario, le borro todo el formulario y hago que aparezca un div con un mensaje de "Token No Válido"

Comment: Podes usar cualquier metodo de hasheo disponible para generarlo, yo opté por ese por ser de pocos caracteres~

Comment: regalame el codigo, para ver cómo está, por favor

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir estos atributos a la etiqueta body, todo y que no es 100% eficaz.

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="return false">
```

Esto lo que hace es bloquear el click derecho del raton en tu pagina.

Comment: Desactivando JS se pasa ese bloqueo de seguridad

Comment: Y el `onkeydown="return false"` impedirá que se pueda escribir nada en los campos de texto (si alguno), lo cual haría el formulario inservible.

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que el `$id` lo obtienes mediante `GET` o `SESSION` en tu `input`de tipo `hidden`.

Podrías crear un [`hash`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.hash.php) de dicho `id` y incluirlo mediante un `input` de tipo `hidden`, y después con [`hash_equals`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.hash-equals.php) podrías comprobar si coincide con el valor obtenido por `GET`.

**Id obtenido por GET**

```
//Supongamos que obtienes el ID por GET.
if (filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {       
   $id = $_GET['id'];       
   $hash_id = hash('ripemd160', $id);
}
```

[`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php), filtra una variable con el filtro que se indique.

**Control formulario**

```
//Reseteo variables inputs.
$id_frm = $hash_frm = NULL;

//Comprobamos que esta definido el formulario
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Obtenemos datos formulario.
    $id_frm = $_POST['id']; 
    $hash_frm = $_POST['hash_id'];//Id haseado obtenido desde formulario.

    //Verdadero datos formulario
    if ($id_frm && $hash_frm) { 

        //Haseamos ID obtenido por Get para comprobación.
        $get_id =   hash('ripemd160', $_GET['id']);

        //Comprobamos que los Hash coinciden.
        if (hash_equals($get_id, $hash_frm)) {  
            //Continuas...
            //Actualizas tus datos en Base de Datos mediante su ID.
            //echo 'El HASH esta correcto';
        } else {
            echo "El HASH no coincide.";
        }       

    }

}
```

**Posible formulario:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
    <!-- Añades tus inputs a actualizar. -->    
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hash_id" value="<?php echo $hash_id; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Actualizar" />
</form>
```